# What does mediainfo mean when it says a video is truncated?

Tags: files, video, ffmpeg, multimedia, integrity

I have two ways of checking for damaged video files. The first is using `mediainfo` and runs instantly:

```
mediainfo "$1" | grep --color 'IsTruncated'
```

The second is manually going through the video frame by frame in `ffmpeg` (takes several minutes of intense processing):

```
ffmpeg -v error -i "$1" -f null -
```

I understand what `IsTruncated` means if a video has been moved or downloaded and is interrupted. The file is too small, and video will stop playing once it hits that spot. But occasionally the first script will tell me there is a video that is truncated, but it plays just fine and all the way to the end. And when run, the second script doesn't give any error message at all.

What does `IsTruncated` mean if the video seems to be fine? Is it possible to find out how much or which parts seem to be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Media can be stored with various encodings and containers. These encodings and containers will have either (1) **Media Size** in the Headers or (2) **End-of-stream** markers (sequence of bytes) at the end.  We can consider Media "IsTruncated", when the **Media Size in Header does not match Size on Disk, or End-of-stream marker is not found**. In these cases, Media Players may Play the content, while Possible & until the stream gets Depleted.

Additionally, (3) containers may have **multiple alternate streams** including audio streams or subtitles or Cover Art Images listed in the Headers. Some of these streams or Images might be **corrupted and/or missing**. Even when Playback is smooth with 1 video stream + 1 audio stream, the container is exactly not complete and Media "IsTruncated" due to corrupted/missing content.

You could use Players like VLC and check the Media Properties and watch the errors when Playing with various alternate stream choices.
You could also use Media Editing tools to check the Properties with Details & verifications.